# Tag Manager Event Tracking set up, but data not showing in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up google analytics ("GA") and google tag manager ("GTM") and have been trying to send data from GTM to GA to create a custom report. Unfortunately, I have not been able to retrieve data from the custom report section of GA as shown below:
[image]

**My objective is as follows:** For each page, I would use GTM to capture (A) special links clicked on page (B) other links clicked on page and (C) page views. Then in GA, I would use [(A)+(B)] / (C) to get my Click Through Rate. I would then use google custom reports to filter by the various pages clicked on my site.

### My setup is as follows

#### Google tag manager configuration

1) Create triggers

Trigger for (A) 
[image: Trigger configuration for A]

Trigger for (B)
[image: Trigger configuration for B]

2) Create tag configuration

Tag configuration for (A)
[image: Tag configuration for (A)]

Tag configuration for (B)
[image: Tag configuration for (B)]

Tag configuration for (C)
[image: Tag configuration for (C)]

I am pretty sure my tags are working fine since they all fire.
[image]

#### Google analytics configuration

1) Create Custom Metric
[image]

2) Create Custom Dimension
[image]

3) Create Calculated Metric

`( {{Page clicked - Outbound manual links (GTM Metric)}} + {{Page clicked - Auto director (GTM Metric)}} ) / {{Page view (GTM Metric)}}`

4) Create Custom Report

As can be seen from the report, there is no data being pulled in.
[image]

Comment: What the GA Settings variable looks like? Have you tried verifying in Network tab of Developer tools in Chrome or using an extension like Tag Assistant recordings that your hits are being sent to GA servers?

Comment: @maggieto Thanks for the reply. I am able to verify that hits are being sent to GA servers. https://imgur.com/a/WtG8h. The 3 events corresponds to the 3 items I am tracking ie. A, B and C. I tried following this tutorial here exactly: `http://mixedanalytics.com/blog/custom-metric-ga-google-tag-manager/` and it did not make mention of GA settings variable so I had not touched it.

Comment: Just wondering if this has got anything to do with the data layer? I had not inserted any custom code into wordpress to deal with it?

Comment: I highly recommend you to use the google analytics debugger extension for chrome since it will tell you if the hit to analytics was actually send or not. Some time the tag firing is not the same as the hit going through.

Comment: @marco Thanks alot Marco, I would have a go at it.

Comment: Also, try to limit the custom report to just date and a single metric to see if there's any data recorded in GA.